# Calculating % by Dividing Filtered Matrix Columns from Tables Related on 2 Attributes in MS Power BI

Tags: datatable, powerbi

This question is related to a simpler problem, posted here:
[Calculating % by Dividing Filtered Matrix Columns in MS Power BI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59718162/calculating-by-dividing-filtered-matrix-columns-in-ms-power-bi)

**Given**: There are 2 (or more) attributes (e.g. 'Date' and 'Location') rather than just 1 (e.g. 'Date'), on which the tables have to be connected. In this case, both tables have to be filtered by date, as well as location, as in the following example:

Table 4:

```
Date_1  Location_1  Numerator
01-Jan-19   NY      5
05-Feb-19   CA      4
04-Apr-19   WA      1
07-May-19   OR      3
11-Jun-19   ND      5
22-Jun-19   NY      4
25-Jul-19   MN      5
31-Aug-19   NY      1
03-Sep-19   NY      4
25-Oct-19   MI      5
```

Table 5:

```
Date_2  Location_2  Denominator
03-Jan-19   NY      7
05-Jan-19   NY      9
16-Feb-19   CA      8
22-Feb-19   CA      7
04-Mar-19   AZ      10
18-Mar-19   ND      8
24-Apr-19   WA      8
25-Apr-19   WA      8
01-May-19   OR      10
10-May-19   OR      8
04-Jun-19   ND      8
08-Jun-19   NY      7
03-Jul-19   MN      8
18-Jul-19   MN      6
23-Aug-19   NY      10
31-Aug-19   NY      9
03-Sep-19   NY      9
20-Sep-19   NY      7
03-Oct-19   MI      7
27-Oct-19   MI      6
```

Tables 4 and 5 can be pivoted to get something like the following:

Table 4 Pivot:

```
Sum of Numerator                2019 Months                     
    Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Location Total
Location                                            
CA      4                                   4
MI                                      5   5
MN                          5               5
ND                      5                   5
NY  5                   4       1   4       14
OR                  3                       3
WA              1                           1
Total 5 4       1   3   9   5   1   4   5   37
```

Table 5 Pivot:

```
Sum of Denominator  2019 Months                                     
    Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Location Total
Location                                            
AZ          10                              10
CA      15                                  15
MN                          14              14
ND          8           8                   16
NY  16                  7       19  16      58
OR                  18                      18
WA              16                          16
MI                                      13  13
Total 16 15 18  16  18  15  14  19  16  13  160
```

The desired output is as follows:

Table 6:

```
                2019 Months                                     
    Jan    Feb      Mar     Apr     May     Jun     Jul     Aug     Sep     Oct    Location Total
Location                                            
CA                                                                          38.46%  38.46%
MN                                                  35.71%                          35.71%
ND                  0.00%                   62.50%                                  31.25%
NY  31.25%                                  57.14%          5.26%   25.00%          24.14%
OR                                  16.67%                                          16.67%
WA                          6.25%                                                   6.25%
Ttl 31.25%  26.67%  0.00%   6.25%   16.67%  60.00%  35.71%  5.26%   25.00%  38.46%  23.13%
```

**Problem**: The % calculated in Power BI is wrong, when the data are visualized in Matrix format similar to Table 6. I thought that Tables 4 and 5 could be linked with connecting them all on 'Location' and 'Date' attributes by using unique calendar and location lists. However, this does not work, because "Ambiguous paths..." error is generated when trying to connect Table 4 and 5 with calendar table, each on 'Date' attribute, and also Table 4 and 5 with location table, each on 'Location' attribute.

**Question**: How can one obtain correct results as in Table 6 in Power BI, using the equivalent of Tables 4 and 5?

[Data relationship diagram can be found here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syhB6.png)

Comment: When you attempted to connect Date and Location tables, did you by any chance tried to make them bi-directional?

Comment: @RADO: I tried both bi-directional and one-directional 'Cross filter direction' settings applied to Data Table - Calendar and Data Table - Location relationships in 'Manage Relationships' pane. Only 1 bi-directional relationship is permitted between Data Table and Calendar, or Data Table and Location. With 2 Data Tables connecting to Calendar, for example, 'Ambiguous paths...' error occurs when 'Cross filter direction' = 'Both' and 'Table <...> already has a relationship...' error occurs when 'Apply security filter in both directions' is checked.

Comment: With 'Cross filter direction' = 'Single' for all relationships, "There's already a relationship between these two columns" error occurs. Currently, I have Calendar |1->*| Table 4, Calendar |1->*| Table 5, Location |1->*| Table 5, Location (Copy) |1->*| Table 4, Location (Copy) |1<->1| Location.

Comment: can you post a picture of your current data model diagram?

Comment: @RADO, thank you for your comment, I included the picture link in my original post.

Comment: can you explain why you have 2 site tables and why they are connected to each other?

Comment: @RADO, I have 2 'Site' tables, because I cannot connect my 'Data Tables' 1 and 2 to both the same 'Calendar' and 'Site', as Power BI gives "Ambiguous paths..." error, since, as I understand, it tries to use conflicting keys from 'Calendar' and 'Site'. Thus, I am trying to avoid the ambiguity by connecting one of the 'Data Tables' to a "dummy" 'Site (2)' table, which is a copy of 'Site' table, and then connecting 'Site (2)' to 'Site' to establish the relationship between them, which should be 1:1, but "The cardinality ... isn't valid for this relationship" error arises then, prompting many:1.